# block requests on apache, my ip address was someone else's before

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

I have a simple webserver set up on an amazon ec2 instance, but the ip assigned to it must have been someone elses before because the logs are littered with requests to webpages and images that aren't there.

From the looks of it, the IP assigned to my webserver used to belong to a food blog or something, and a specific still-running website has linked to images that used to exist on this server. Is there any way to block all requests that are forwarded through this still-running website, or some other solution to clean up my log files/lessen the load on my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really block them, but if your server is running on an EBS based instance you can:

- stop the instance (right click on the instance in the [AWS Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/home))
- start the instance again.

You should get a new IP and you'll need to fix up your DNS to point to it.

Your site will be unavailable for a few minutes while this happens but hopefully the problem will go away, or at least become Somebody Else's Problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a VirtualHost that has a ServerName and ServerAlias of the previously used domain-name. Then within, either block all access to this site or redirect all requests to where-ever you want.

```
<VirtualHost ip.address:80>
  ServerName foodblog.com
  ServerAlias www.foodblog.com

  # 404 everything
  order allow,deny
  deny from all

  #or redirect everything
  Redirect  / http://some.other.website/
</VirtualHost>
```

If the requests are mostly linked-to images, you could even create your own image that says 'take this link out' and redirect to it so it gets someone's attention.

Comment: He will still get the traffic though, and depending on the volume he is not going to want to pay for traffic he doesn't care about. He will also have an odd VirtualHost configuration hanging around forever, so I feel that my earlier suggestion is a cleaner solution.